# Linear probing number of probe sequences

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

According to Cormen book,number of probe sequences possible in linear probing if hash function is given as

$h(k,i) =( h' (k) + i)$ $\text % m $ is **m**

if h'(k) = k modulo 5  and m = 10, then how can we have 10 distinct probe sequences?

Initial probe is decided by h'(k), so number of probe sequences should be limited by h'(k) and should be 5 right ?